# How to Map sub-State in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have created a state **~/store/modules/general/index.js**

There are **get_info** and **get_pages** Actions,

states **info** and **pages**,

When i use

```
...mapActions({
getInfo: 'modules/general/get_info'
getPages: 'modules/general/get_pages'
})
```

Works fine,
but when i try to access it via

```
...mapState({
Info: 'modules/general/info'
Pages: 'modules/general/pages'
})
```

**Return undefined**

When i use

```
...mapState({
modules: 'modules'
})
```

this return all my substates plz help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to map the state twice for both info, pages states like,

```
computed: {
    ...mapState('modules/general/info', ['get_info']),
    ...mapState('modules/general/pages', ['get_pages']) 
}
```

Another way you can map the states like,

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('modules/general', {
    info: state => state.info,
    pages: state => state.pages
  })
},
```

Refer [Binding-helpers-with-namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

Comment: computed: {
    ...mapState('modules/general', {
      Pages: (state) => state.pages,
      Info: (state) => state.info
    })
  },
There is best way to get state thx for your help. And big thanks for refer it really useful

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you on your way to only get the state you actually wants, instead of all of the states on the store.

From this approach, it means that you should have your `store` attached to Vue already, but i guess you already have from the code you're showing.

You might have to swap `'general'` with `'modules/general'`

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('general', {
    info: state => state.info
  })
}
```